# How to add AngularJS directives to .NET WebForms Update Panels?

Tags: javascript, .net, angularjs, webforms

I have a project that uses legacy code in .NET and WebForms. The legacy code uses several **Update Panels**.

My hope is to use AngularJS without impacting the legacy code base.

```
<div ng-app="myApp">
    <NS:TheUserControl ID="TheUserControl1" runat="Server" />
</div>
```

Here is the javascript:

```
var app = angular.module("myApp", []);

app.run(function ($rootScope, $compile) {

    function insertDirective() {
        jQuery(targetElementSelector).attr("my-directive", "");
    }

    insertDirective();

    var mgr = Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager.getInstance();
    mgr.add_endRequest(function (sender, args) {

        insertDirective();
        $compile(jQuery(targetElementSelector))($rootScope);

    });

});
```

The code above adds an attribute to an HTML element inside ***NS:TheUserControl***, and the attribute specifies a directive (see directive below).

Then, these steps are used when the update panel changes:

1. Detect the change using Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager (EndRequest listener)
2. Re-add the directive using javascript
3. Run $compile on the newly-inserted directive

Here is the directive:

```
app.directive("myDirective", function () {
    return {
        template: "<span ng-repeat='item in items'>{{item}}</span>"
                + "<span ng-transclude></span>"
        , transclude: true,
        , controller: function ($scope) {
            $scope.items = ["a", "b", "c"];
        }
    };
});
```

This almost works... except...

**Problem 1:**

AngularJS creates a scope associated with each instance of a directive. When the update panel inside **NS:TheUserControl** changes the DOM, the previous scopes are still present. I can see this in Batarang (a Chrome developer tool for AngularJS).

**Problem 2:**

For a brief moment after the update panels change, I get:

- **abc**  <-- Initial page load
- **abcabc**  <-- Subsequent update panel changes
- **abcabcabc**
- **abcabcabcabc**

Then, a moment later after each update panel change, the content jumps back to the correct:

- **abc**

**Questions:**

So, how do I either:

- Remove the orphaned scopes?
- Or, incorporate AngularJS directives in a way that plays nice with the update panels?

Comment: How about including a code sample?

Comment: Can you give us a minimal example that reproduces the issue? As it's written, we can either take your word for it (violating the first rule of debugging) and try to reproduce it ourselves, or we can try to write the entire thing for you.  The former is easier for us to help you.

Comment: I certainly can :)  Please see updated question with code. Thank you for your suggestion!